# Integrating a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Let $a <b$ and let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions.  Suppose that for all $x \in [a,b]$ that $\int_a^x f(t) dt = \int_x^b f(t) dt$. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

I know its basing off of The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus II. And I thought differentiating like the answer below was a way to grasp the concept but I just think I am over complicating it in my mind. I have a habit of doing that.

Comment: I know its basing off of The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus II. And I thought differentiating like the answer below was the right way to get a grasp on this but I just think I am over complicating it or something.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If you differentiate
$$\int_a^x f(t) dt = \int_x^b f(t) dt$$
you obtain
$$
f(x)=-f(x).
$$

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that a=b?

Comment: No, it would not.

Comment: Okay I just took some time to work on this and I believe I solved it. It may be different than what you were suggesting but either way acomplishes the task, it may look a little sloppy b/c LaTex isnt loading right..... If you integrate the equations you get F(x) - F(a) = F(b) - F(x) which simplifies to F(x) = (F(a) + F(b)) / 2 which when we differentiate we get f(x) = 0 because the right side of the equality is a constant so differentiating a constant equals 0.